# How to rebuild uwsgi with xml = True

Tags: uwsgi

I have installed uwsgi in my server. But when I can't use command uwsgi -x django_socket.xml.
It said

```
uwsgi: invalid option -- 'x'
getopt_long() error
```

Someone told me that i should rebuild it cause i build uwsgi without xml support. Then i check the uwsgi docs. 
Then i downloads the Django-2.0.4.tar.gz again, cause i remove it after i installed it last time. 
And i rebuild it with command:

```
python uwsgiconfig.py --build
```

And i saw a report

```
pcre = True
kernel = Linux
malloc = libc
execinfo = False
ifaddrs = True
ssl = True
zlib = True
locking = pthread_mutex
plugin_dir = .
timer = none
yaml = embedded
json = False
filemonitor = inotify
routing = True
debug = False
capabilities = False
xml = False
event = epoll
```

but it seems does't work, the xml still false. What should i do?

Answer (score 1):

install libxml2 or expat development headers and re-run make. The build system will automatically detect their availability

Comment: I had some try. and it said 'Package expat-2.0.1-11.el6_2.x86_64 already installed and latest version' when i execute the command 'yum install expat'. The same to the libxml2. Does that mean i already get them? If so , why do i failed in the command uwsgi -x

Comment: you need to install development packages, what you have found are the plain library. You misses headers.